Is the reaction 2 Hg + O2 → 2HgO a reversible reaction?
Is $\ce{2 Hg + O2 -> 2HgO}$ a reversible reaction ?
Are the relative importance of $\ce{2 Hg + O2 -> 2HgO}$ and $\ce{2HgO -> 2 Hg + O2}$ dependent of the temperature ?
If so (yes), what is the fundamental reason of the evolution of the relative importance with temperature ?

All chemical reactions are reversable. For the fundamental reason look to the Gibbs free energies and their dependence on temperature, pressure, etc.

First, all chemical reactions are reversible and all have a rate that depends on the temperature.
Second, the synthesis of $\ce{HgO}$ has a rate that is dependent on the temperature. This is quite easy to show experimentally. Imagine for example, that $1.00$ gram $\ce{HgO}$ is put in the bottom of a test tube, then the tube is fixed in an inclined position, and the lower part of the tube (and only this part) is heated by a fixed Bunsen flame. If the temperature of the flame is higher than about $\pu{500°C}$, oxygen is produced that can be recognized by a brand or burning wood. Simultaneously gaseous mercury is produced that gets condensed like a mirror in the colder part of the tube (middle of the tube).$$\ce{2 HgO -> 2 Hg + O2  \tag{1}}$$ Furthermore, if the flame is maintained in the same position in the lower part of the tube, a small red-orange band of $\ce{HgO}$ slowly appears just under the mercury mirror. Its formation is due the reversed reaction $$\ce{2Hg + O2 -> 2 HgO \tag{2}}$$ This shows that reaction ($1$) is more important at high temperatures, and reaction ($2$) occurs at lower temperatures. Both reactions ($1$) and ($2$) are part of an equilibrium which is moved according to ($1$) at temperatures higher than $500$°C, and moved according to ($2$) at lower temperatures than $\pu{500}°$C (but not too low}. But both $\ce{Hg}$ and $\ce{HgO}$ are stable at room temperatures. So both reactions ($1$} and {$2$} have a negligible rates at ordinary temperature. This shows that both reaction rates are increasing with temperature.
